# Mysql query: INNER JOIN and SELECT * that is not null from any table

Tags: mysql

For example i'm doing inner join on the same table.
I want to pick those fields either from table 1 or table 2 where value is not null.

Here is query as an example:

```
SELECT a2.*,a.town
FROM `ads` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN discounts d ON d.ad_id=a.id
INNER JOIN ads a2 ON a2.id=d.discount_ad_id
LEFT JOIN `departments` AS `dp` ON dp.department_id = a.department
LEFT JOIN `map_towns` AS `mt` ON mt.town_id = a.town
WHERE (a.department = 9 OR a.department = 15)
GROUP BY `d`.`discount_id`
```

a2 have town fields as well, but i can have null value. I need to pick a2.town if it's not null and a.town if it is.
This is related to all others fields. :)

Is it possible?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a2.*, COALESCE(a2.town, a.town)
FROM    `ads` AS `a`
JOIN    discounts d
ON      d.ad_id = a.id
JOIN    ads a2
ON      a2.id = d.discount_ad_id
LEFT JOIN
        `departments` AS `dp`
ON      dp.department_id = a.department
LEFT JOIN
        `map_towns` AS `mt`
ON      mt.town_id = a.town
WHERE   a.department IN (9, 15)
GROUP BY
        `d`.`discount_id`
```

Note that `LEFT JOIN` on `discounts` is redundant in your query: the `NULL` records will never be returned since they will never be matched by the following `INNER JOIN` to `ads a2`.

Comment: Is it possible to do it in dynamic way? Without need to manually do it with each field?

Comment: @Beck: I don't understand the question. What do mean by "doing it manually"?

Comment: COALESCE(a2.*, a.*) i mean this way is possible somehow? :)

Comment: @Beck: ah. No, you will have to do it separately for each field.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ANSI function COALESCE, or the MySQL function IFNULL. Alias the column as required

```
SELECT
   a2.id,
   a2.col2,
   coalesce(a2.town, a.town) town,
   IFNULL(a2.city, a.city) city,
 ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `COALESCE` function, returns the first argument that is not null.

`SELECT COALESCE(a2.town, a.town)`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Is it possible to do it in dynamic way? Without need to manually do it with each field?